# How do I have 199 reputation on Meta if I haven't asked questions on here before?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation

I haven't asked a question on here before, but yet my meta reputation is 199. How?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You reputation on a child meta is the [same reputation you have on the main site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66412/why-is-the-meta-reputation-derived-directly-from-the-parent-site). You have 201 reputation on Super User, and so you have 201 on Super User Meta. You cannot earn rep on any Meta, except for Meta Stack Overflow.