# How can someone have only 1 reputation?

Tags: bug, reputation

I found a user with only one reputation even though he had answered previous questions and seemed to have quite an activity on superuser.

is it a hack, a bug or a possible superuser policy/ban?

(I have hidden the name for some kind of confidentiality even though it should not be so hard to find back as our user profile are public, so feel free to ask the link to the user if it helps to answer)

[image: 1 reputation]

Comment: It is a valid question and answer I find here is helpful. I am wondering what merited this question to earn 2 downvotes? someone trying to suppress this question or trying to hurt question poster's reputation or what?

Comment: @VSRawat, thanks for the empathy. I cannot answer your question but for sure it is not to hurt my reputation: I noticed my reputation did not decrease/increase from those downvotes/your upvote(I assume), the answer is here: https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4683/how-do-i-have-199-reputation-on-meta-if-i-havent-asked-questions-on-here-before?rq=1.
Basically Meta has no impact on reputation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

User that have been suspended by moderators will have their reputation set to 1 for the duration of a suspension.

Alternatively the user could have given away all their reputation on bounties.

Comment: ok, good to know, it then looks like a suspended account, otherwise the curve would have more staircases. But does it means that suspended account can still log in and ask a question with 1rep?

Comment: No. Suspended users cannot post questions, answers or comments. The site is effectively read-only for them until the suspension ends.

Comment: Ok thanks, I would then still find it interesting to know why is the reputation dropped to 1 when the account is suspended, since the user cannot edit anything anyway?

Comment: @Jonathan - The lowest amount of reputation somebody can have is a single reputation point.  Permissions to the site are based on the amount of reputation you have.  Suspending users is something that has to be done at times, but something the Stack Exchange developers don't actually want to support specifically, so in addition to being unable to ask questions or answer them, all privileges have to be taken away also.

Comment: @Ramhound such users can be put in moderation mode, that all their questions, answers, and comments are moderated by a human before they become visible to other and if the moderator doesn't find merit in them, he can refuse to make them visible and inform the user so. Suspension or stealing hard earned reputation is un-democratic methinks.

Comment: @VSRawat - Moderators are volunteers.  If users cannot follow the rules the suspension is the only recourse.  Is this “moderation mode” something that exists or are you suggesting it?

Comment: @VSRawat this isn't a democracy, it is a [merit-based benevolent dictatorship](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/321).